# Redirect activity after facebook login

Tags: android, android-activity, facebook-login

I'm using Android Facebook SDK (4.01) to login to my app with Facebook. The facebook login from my MainActivity succeeds and then I use Intent to procced to next activity. That part works.

After that in my new activity (MainLobby) I want to able to logout from facebook and return to my previous MainActivity, by pressing back button. For some reason when I press back the MainLobby closes, but has another MainLobby activity behind it. So I have to press back button twice to get back to MainActivity. Why is that?

Main Activity class code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    fbloginBT = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbloginBT);
    callback = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    fbloginBT.registerCallback(callback, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
            Intent mainLobby = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainLobby.class);
            startActivity(mainLobby);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
    fbloginBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Main Lobby class code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    else if (searchView.isShown() && !isClosed){
        searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();  //collapse your ActionView
        searchView.setQuery("", false);       //clears your query without submit
        isClosed = true;
    }
    else {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I works correct on emulator, in Android Studio. It works as described above when I test it on an Android phone device.

Comment: In your app log , "onSuccess" is wrote twice ?

Comment: No, it writes just once.

Comment: But it writes twice when I run it on the Android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
private boolean isMainLobbyStarted = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    fbloginBT = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbloginBT);
    callback = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    fbloginBT.registerCallback(callback, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
            Intent mainLobby = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainLobby.class);
            if(!isMainLobbyStarted) {
                startActivity(mainLobby);
                isMainLobbeyStarted = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
    fbloginBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah though about this myself. It solves the problem, without a question. I was more interested whether it had something to do with the Facebook SDK, but apparently the code is not the issue. For some reason it just calls onSuccess twice. Why? We don't know.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows and try ,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
else if (searchView.isShown() && !isClosed){
    searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();  //collapse your ActionView
    searchView.setQuery("", false);       //clears your query without submit
    isClosed = true;
}

LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: No it's the same. Updated the question above with more info.