# Redirect activity to Frontpage activity after facebook login

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, android-facebook

I am trying to accomplish a redirection to a Frontpage activity after facebook login,I have tried this  given code but didn't workout 
yes also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805604/redirect-activity-after-facebook-login) but didn't work out
Code from Login activity.

```
public  class login extends FragmentActivity {


private boolean isMainLobbyStarted = false;

CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private loginResult loginResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        System.out.println("onSuccess");
        Intent mainLobby = new Intent(login.this, Frontpage.class);
        if(!isMainLobbyStarted) {
            startActivity(mainLobby);
            isMainLobbeyStarted = true;
    }

}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

Messages gradle built

```
Error:(54, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing
Error:(35, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(35, 16) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(35, 30) error: ';' expected
Error:(35, 54) error: ';' expected
Error:(49, 36) error: ';' expected
Error:(49, 53) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(49, 58) error: not a statement
Error:(49, 68) error: ';' expected
Error:(49, 81) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted the answer with the complete set of coding please feel free to ask me if you find your self with an error

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;

public  class login extends FragmentActivity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, Frontpage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}